# "#2014 - Commands out of sync" при запросе EXPLAIN

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) as co FROM todo WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_todo_send uts WHERE uts.id_todo = todo.id AND uts.id_user = $id_user)
```

При выполнения команды происходит ошибка:

> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подставьте значение вместо `$id_user`.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил